# Why was this deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702310/using-distinct-along-with-group-by-in-sql-server/), but it was deleted. It said:

> One or the other or both you get the same query plan and the same results. 
>   Test for yourself.

It is an exact tested answer to the stated question. Why was it deleted?

The comment of query plan not the same on PostgreSQL does not apply. The question is tagged [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server).

Comment: That was probably more suitable to be posted as comment than an actual answer.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. I converted it into a comment. "Test for yourself", would certainly not be a complete answer to the question, and a comment instead.

Comment: @BhargavRao I still think it is a valid tested answer but OK

Comment: @Paparazzi, If you can edit it and make it a complete answer, I'd certainly undelete it. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao It is old with an accepted answer.  I am going to let it be.

Answer (score 18):

There are two actual questions in the question you answered:

1. > Is there any purpose for using both DISTINCT and GROUP BY in SQL?
2. > Does anyone know of any situations where both DISTINCT and GROUP BY needs to be used, to get any specific desired results?

Your answer was:

> One or the other or both you get the same query plan and the same results.
>   Test for yourself.

That doesn't really *look* like an answer to either question. As [Bhargav Rao said in a comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339301/why-was-this-deleted#comment419968_339301), it looks more like a comment.

It arguably is an answer because you could read it as, "No, there's no reason to use both because they do the same thing." Leaving aside whether or not that would be a correct statement, it would be an answer. The problem is that it didn't *look* like an answer to either part of the question.

All that said, at first glance, I didn't think it was an answer, either. I probably would have deleted it, too, if it came up in the flag queue.

Comment: If is supposed to be one question per question.  I am OK with just leaving it deleted.

Comment: @Paparazzi You're right that there should be one question per Question. The two parts of that Question are really just two ways of asking the same thing (is there a scenario where this is good, and can you give me an example). Anyway, just wanted to help shed some light on what happened.

Comment: I don't agree with two ways of the same thing.  If you are returning the columns in the group by then they are the same (the example given by the OP).  If you are doing some aggregation (e.g. max, sum) you can get in a situation of duplicates but it is usually because the query is messed up. I have never seen a good example both used to produce a desired result.  I am OK leaving deleted but I really did test the query plans in MSSQL.

Comment: @Paparazzi My point wasn't really to debate whether your answer was correct. I'm not sure whether it is or not, and that's not something moderators look at when we review flags. The point is just that the answer didn't seem to really address either part of the question, at least not without a little mental gymnastics.

Comment: Cool I am OK with just leaving it deleted