# Advice on how to handle "one line" answers

Tags: discussion, review-audits

The last time I noticed that I fell multiple times through an audit because I accepted an "one line" answer which wasn't an answer. (I totally agree with this)

So I get a little bit confused because in the past I flagged some "one line" answers as "low quality" or "not an answer" and these flags were declined.

I read a little bit and found some explanations **[here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers)** and **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)** or the "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" in the help center.
But all this doesn't help me do decide when an answer is not an answer or when it's only a really bad answer (referred to one line answers).

- Can you give me some advices how you decide this? Or
- Should I just skip all this answers to avoid a failed audition?
- Should I flag them as "low quality" or "not an answer" and risk that maybe the person who gets my flag disagrees?
- Should I accept them as answers and risk to get a failed audition?

But someone has to know how to handle this type of answers, because if everyone would skip this kind of answers they will handeled from no one.

Or is it just a matter of opinion how to handle this answers and it depends on the person who gets the flag?

I can add a picture of my last failed audit, but the answer is already deleted so I think its not really usefull.

Edit here is the pic of my last failed audit:

[image]

Link to question: [Visual Studio 2008 can't connect to SQL Server 2014 database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31552409/660921)

Comment: For me it would help if you provide the link. I find it easier to advice based on an actual example.

Comment: It's possible that you failed the audit not because it was a one-line answer, but rather because it had other problems. As Rene indicated, it would be helpful if you would show some concrete examples (otherwise suggestions/answers become very *theoretisch* :-)) Re: `the answer is already deleted so I think its not really useful` -> If you have more than 10k reputation you can see deleted answers, so it *would* be useful :-)

Comment: ok, I added the picture of it.

Comment: I honestly think that is an answer and shouldn't have been converted to a comment. It is not an elaborate answer, that is true, still ....

Comment: see also: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: @gnat thank you, I saw that question too, but thought that there must be a way to "learn" whats the difference between that answers.

Comment: @Toto I read this question too. It says "_What not to flag:
Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still an answer_ ". But I had some auditions where I accepted the answer because it was a bad answer and I failed it. So I was confused what to do because I want to do something which is maybe more helpful than only skip. But during clicking to all your provided links I found [**this**](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6681) post. So I think the best I can do is just leave a comment beneath the bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, if the answer has no value it is OK to consider using flags. That goes for anything in the form of *Look here* or *Try this* or [*test for your self*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339301/why-was-this-deleted)

The moderator [handled that answer based on a flag](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34995188#34995188), they do so without having much context: they only see the answer. I admit the answer is not very elaborate and without knowledge of the technology used here it could be easy interpreted as a non-answer.

The question however is about the inability by some IDE to connect to newer versions of a database. The current answer on that question states that you can't do that.

This new answer however, states correctly that you can use the OleDB driver to connect. That is because OleDB almost connect to anything from a Windows platform and it does that since somewhere the mid 90's.

So, in conclusion: I think you're right. That answer is an answer. It shouldn't have been flagged, the moderator shouldn't have converted it to a comment. It isn't a great answer, it can use an edit to make more clear how that might solve the issue.

The moderator who handled that flag pinged me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34995276#34995276)

> undeleted that post. (Just in case it becomes a bad audit for another user)

Comment: Meh. It is still missing the part that would actually make it an answer… Something that would connect the dots between a seemingly-random thought and the question. Something like the way you idealistically represent the answer here: *"That is because OleDB almost connect to anything from a Windows platform and it does that since somewhere the mid 90's."* I don't know why everyone is so quick to embrace crappy answers on Meta. Obviously I work too hard writing good ones, when I could just dash off one-liners and everyone would have to charitably interpret them as being worth saving & protecting

Comment: @CodyGray It is not a great answer but it still is one? If I interpret your comment correctly you rather see all of us to make the bar much higher instead of the minimal bat it is at the moment?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand why we ban people for posting crap, tell people not to edit crap, and on and on, yet when crap gets flagged, we hem and haw and talk about how maybe it could be an answer if we squint and add 6–8 more lines to it. *In its current form*, I do not agree that this is an answer. It might contain *potential* to become an answer, but that's not the basis I use for evaluation. The problem is not necessarily that it's only one line, the problem is that it doesn't contain enough information. It doesn't explain why, it doesn't explain how, it doesn't say anything *useful*.

Comment: Do you have an idea how this mind shift in raising the bar should be established as atm it looks like my answer is inline with the duplicate which is also an FAQ item. I'm in favor of removing low quality stuff but I also go with the flow. Maybe re-open this so you can elaborate in an answer so you can give a proper argument against my answer?

Comment: I think the problem is everyone on Meta just tries to be helpful, so they repeat what they believe is the official line. No one ever thinks about whether that perspective is correct or not, and when you do try to point that out, everyone jumps on you with, "But I did that and my flag was declined!", so people just give up. No, I don't know how to fix it, so I just complain about in comments to people who leave answers implicitly advocating the status quo.

Comment: OK, that is useful feedback. I see your point and I'll give it a try to be more quality minded in my answer and less following the status-quo. That might need some coaching so please keep those comments coming. Appreciated.