# Why were my flags declined?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation, declined-flags

Recently 5 of my flags were declined. The answers I flagged are these:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41559330/1908331

   The reason for flagging this answer was:

   1. This is not an answer. Not a single line of code. This can be written as a comment and considering the user's reputation (63 at the time) they could easily use the comments section to communicate with the OP.
   2. Technically what they have written is wrong and I also wrote a comment under the answer and pointed that why the answer is wrong. Surprisingly my comment was deleted as well! So now there is an answer which is technically wrong and there is no comment under it to notify other visitors that this information is not correct!

      The reason for declining my flag:

      > declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41560010/1908331

   The reason for flagging this answer was:

   1. This answer if totally irrelevant to the question. The question is a server-side problem which the OP is experiencing and the solution provided by the users who has answered, is client-side solution.
   2. This answer has nothing to do with the question!
   3. Fortunately this time my comment was not deleted under the answer

   The reason for declining my flag:

   > declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41605432/1908331

   The reason for flagging this answer was:

   1. This answer provides no valuable information and is totally irrelevant to the question
   2. Not a single line of code to help the OP solve their problem.
   3. The answer is somehow confusing itself

   The reason for declining my flag:

   > declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41606200/1908331

   The reason for flagging this answer was:

   1. Although this answer is somehow relevant to the question, it's not an actual answer. It is only a comment. I know the user does not have enough reputation to post a comment (reputation was 1 at the time). But when flagging, we have this reason: *This was posted as an answer, **but it does not attempt to answer the question**. It should possibly be an edit, **a comment**, another question, or deleted altogether.* There, I had the reason to flag it...
   2. I wrote a comment under the answer and explained if the user who wrote the answer increase his reputation, then they could use comments section to communicate with the OP.
   3. Not a single line of code to explain how to solve the problem

   The reason for declining my flag:

   > declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41214845/1908331

   The reason for flagging this answer was:

   1. Come on, do you even consider this answer as a comment?!
   2. Not a single line of code
   3. No explanation on how this answer will solve the OP's problem

   The reason for declining my flag:

   > declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

---

I have been active on SO for some months now. I have been using flagging very care fully and tried my be to be helpful. I have 140 helpful flags (I'm aware that this number is nothing compared to many other users) and only during tje past 2 days, 4 of my flags have been declined (and the fifth one about 1 month ago). Not just declined, but declined wrongfully, at least in my opinion. Not to mention that I only have these 5 declined flags.

I have read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187781/why-was-my-flag-declined) and the accepted answer has well explained the reason that I think my case is the same. But it raises a big question for me.

In the answer, it's said that:

> In general, when flagging, you have to realize that the moderator who
>   deals with the flag may not be familiar with the technologies that are
>   referenced in the question, so what might look like a non-answer to an
>   expert, might look like a bad answer (or at least a reasonable attempt
>   at one) to someone else. As a guideline, if an answer even appears as
>   if it is trying to answer the question, then a flag would likely be
>   declined.

And in my opinion that is totally wrong. Why would a moderator who does not have enough information about a technology (programming language) decide about a flag that has been raised on that language? I mean no offence to the moderators, but a moderator can be an expert in Java, but does not have enough in-depth information about PHP. Why do they have to decide on a flag on PHP? Just because they can?

This is not fair to both the user who has flagged the answer and other users who may see this answer and try to solve their problem with this wrong answer!

Also, I think trying to answer is not enough. Stack Overflow is a highly specialized site for asking questions and getting expert answers. In my opinion this site should be the last hope of every desperate programmer who has programming problems. So when someone asks a question on this site, users should try their best to provide the best and most detailed answers. posting an answer ans just saying "Try to use ajax" is not an answer. It's not even a try to answer. Why would a moderator consider this types of answers valuable enough to not delete them?!

Note: I have read these questions and their answers as well:

- [Not an answer flag declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188083/not-an-answer-flag-declined)
- [Why was this 'not-an-answer' flag declined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178478/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined)
- [Was my flag declined unfairly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161236/was-my-flag-declined-unfairly)
- [When should the "Not an Answer" flag be used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107216/when-should-the-not-an-answer-flag-be-used)

But when this answer states:

> A bad or a wrong answer is still technically an answer. Moderators
>   aren't here to judge the correctness of answers. That's what the
>   voting system is for, so the right way to handle those is to downvote,
>   edit, or leave a comment.

I don't think it's OK. Why is a wrong answer technically an answer? In this case there should be tons and tons of bad answers from beginners who have just answered with the hope of getting accepted (and increase their reputation) without sufficient technical information and explanation in their answers. And if so, then why even we have "low-quality answer" flag at all? This will decrease the reputation of Stack Overflow. Why would other users see such low-quality answers under a question?

Comment: Just one observation: "not a single line of code" is completely irrelevant, in both questions and answers. Code is not a *must*. Many great question and answers feature not a single line of code.

Comment: Why migrated it from meta to here?

Comment: @deceze I know and I was not talking in general about all the answers. I'm talking about these 5 specific answers. I'm totally aware of that depending about the question, the answer may be very useful and do not contain even one line of code. But these questions needed and answer which had to have code and explain how to solve the problem in code...

Comment: @vaso123 because this question only applies to a single site, which is an off-topic close reason on MSE.

Comment: If you follow your numbers in lists with a dot instead of a hyphen, the formatting will come out much better.

Comment: @rene It is intresting form me, since, it does not a programming question, even if is about only for one site. Fortunatly I am not start on election :)

Comment: All that typing and not a single one required mod attention.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41559330/1908331

Is it a *great* answer? No. Does it *attempt* to answer the question? Absolutely. The author apparently thought they had identified the problem and is trying to convey it as answer to the OP.

> 2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41560010/1908331

Is it the *correct* answer to the OP's problem? *Probably not.* Does it *attempt* to answer the question? Absolutely.

> 3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41605432/1908331

Is it a *good* answer? Gosh no. In fact, it's pretty terrible. It should probably be deleted as *Very Low Quality*. Does it *attempt* to answer the question? Kinda looks like it does, yes.

> 4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41606200/1908331

Is it a *complete* answer? Meeeeh… hardly. Does it *attempt* to answer the question? It certainly does, even if it's very lacking.

> 5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41214845/1908331

Is it a great answer? Not really. Does it *attempt* to answer the question? Absolutely. The author is pointing out a typo/incorrect class name which may or may not solve the problem.

---

"Not An Answer" means that there's absolutely no correlation to an answer.

> I like pancakes on Tuesdays when penguins row my car!

> Hi, I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

> Buy these <a>man-pills</a> from this man in Nigeria!

*These* kinds of posts are *not answers*. But anything that attempts to answer the question, however poorly or misguided, *is an answer.* Please flag as *Very Low Quality* instead **if you think it deserves it.**

Yes, some of those answers probably deserved a flag of some kind of another, but *Not An Answer* was simply **the wrong flag** to raise. The flags all have a specific meaning and are handled by various parts of the community, so it's important to use the right one. Your NAA flags simply didn't fit the intended use case; even if something should have been done about those posts, we have to decline wrong use of flags to keep the system working smoothly.

---

Now, you may disagree with what a NAA flag *should* be used for. That is a separate discussion to be had (and which is continuously being had…). To answer the question why these particular flags *were* declined: this was consistent with [the current definition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/476) of what NAA should be used for.

---

> Why would a moderator who does not have enough information about a technology(programming language) decide about a flag which have been raised on that language?!?

Because moderators moderate *user behaviour*, not technical content. The community as a whole moderates the technical accuracy of answers by voting up or down; moderators see to it that the community as a whole behaves nicely and that quality standards are kept up. We don't need to be an expert in all technical subjects to do so. In fact, it's virtually impossible to apply that standard to moderators, since there are always niche technologies that would be unmoderatable.

Comment: (or downvote if the answer is simply poor)

Comment: Ugh, the whole "attempts to answer the question" rationale again. If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41560010/366904) counts as an attempt to answer the question, I could literally post that as an answer to anything with the [html] or [css] tags. Would that improve the quality of this site?

Comment: Regarding the new paragraph you added, I don't think blaming flaggers for failing to correctly choose between NAA and VLQ flags is a very productive exercise, especially when the available guidance on what those flags mean and where they should be used is so scattered and confusing, and not even moderators have consistent interpretations. Remember that the goal is not to shame people for using the wrong flag, it's to clean up garbage. If you're declining flags for pedantic reasons, you are probably doing it wrong. Aside from that, the community can handle NAA flags, too; they're not mod-only.

Comment: @Cody I agree with that actually. [Some of] those answers could have been deleted anyway, **but the flag should still have been declined.** There are different flags for a reason, they're not all just "somebody needs to look at this". Now, if you want to discuss that some flags should probably be consolidated/removed/changed, you're welcome to. I believe the team is in the process of evaluating flag usage at the moment anyway, so we might see refinements there in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: *6 to 8 weeks* ... someone is getting optimistic ;)

Comment: @deceze Nice to hear they are evaluating the flags. Is there a discussion somewhere on Meta about this, or do you have an inside source? :)

Comment: @Stijn I just overheard it. This is not an official endorsement. Nothing may happen at all. 6 to 8 weeks is a meme, not an actual ETA. There may be no "team" at all and it's all run by monkeys.

Comment: I agree on *1*, *4* and *5*, as they actually pertain to the asked question. But "answers" *2* and *3* are just completely off-base and have no relation to the asked question at all. It's almost like *"any post with any amount of technical information*" is seen as an "attempt to answer the question" these days...

Comment: It's been discussed countless times. No one can agree on what they mean. That's the whole point. That's why I find it odd for you to be implying that there is a self-evident meaning and that it is on that basis you declined the flag. Don't attack the straw man that *all* of the flags are the same. I didn't say that. I was specifically talking about VLQ and NAA. You seem to be conceding that VLQ would have been appropriate, but NAA is not. How are you able to make such a clear distinction between the two of them, when no one else is? If you turn flagging into a minefield, people will stop.

Comment: Also, this is a bit unrelated, but I very much struggle with the dualism here. On the one hand, moderators say not to worry about declined flags, that it's really no big deal. On the other hand, they seem to see flag declension as an education mechanism of sorts, gently reprimanding people for having chosen the wrong flag reason. Both cannot be true simultaneously, and this leads to a massive amount of frustration, both at the moment, and then again during the post-mortem on Meta.

Comment: @Cody I'm not sure what disagreement exactly you're referring to. The [official FAQ has a pretty clear guidance on that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/476). "Thanks", "me too", follow-up questions, attempts to have a conversation with somebody else in the "thread"… those a *not answers.* Anything that more or less says *"here's a solution"*, however bad that solution is, does not fit that criterion.

Comment: @Cody Indeed, declining flags is a signalling mechanism to the flagger that they need to reevaluate their flagging behaviour. Perhaps it drives them to the FAQ, perhaps it prompts a meta post. Any one individual declined flag could be in error on either side of the fence, everyone needs to have some leniency there. *A pattern* of declined flags should probably prompt action by the flagger.

Comment: Surely you haven't missed the countless Meta discussions about the ambiguity of these two flag reasons. That's the disagreement I'm referring to. The "official FAQ" to which you link is itself an example of the ongoing disagreement, with *highly* upvoted comments disagreeing with the interpretation as well as edits adjusting the criteria, including Stijn's, which links [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/), a virtual cornucopia of various interpretations. Martijn has rolled it back, of course. He maintains and protects that answer vigilantly. Doesn't a consensus make.

Comment: @Cody Disagreement in the comments does not a lack of official stance make either. I do not wish to rehash the long thread of disagreements. There's a definition of what NAA means. This is repeated several times in different places. For the most part that I'm aware of mods are trying to stick to that. The mod behaviour in this particular case seems to be perfectly consistent with it as well.

Comment: If you really need to "signal the flagger" then it seems to me that there should be better ways to handle that. This is just shouting [NO SOUP FOR YOU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2lfZg-apSA) because someone didn't follow the rules *to the letter*.

Comment: In the end moderators have to stick to *something*, even if the rules are evolving. Every mod here stuck to the current definition as currently defined in the current FAQ. Nobody ran off and did completely random, inconsistent things. Rules evolve, and when they do mod behaviour will change. I don't see any inconsistencies in this particular case.

Comment: Maybe I'm making my argument too nuanced. The fundamental inconsistency is that flags were declined on garbage posts, which resulted in low-quality content continuing to remain on the site (and thus a failure to solve a fundamental problem affecting all of us), while simultaneously confusing and frustrating someone whose primary goal was to help clean up the site (thus perpetuating future quality problems, since there will be one fewer person willing to point them out). Perhaps moderators should stick to asking themselves whether a flagged post's presence is actually making the site better.

Comment: On an unrelated note, @Cody, I used to follow your advice. "Delete those posts that don't make the site better". What happened later? Meta posts asking why [bad posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339301) were deleted by moderators and about such posts [becoming bad audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341145). So yeah, whatever action those darned mods take, would be held to task on meta. Unless someone shakes up this whole system and goes real mad stating that, "These are bad answers, wipe them away from my sight", I don't think the situation will change.

Comment: @BhargavRao score and answer in your first example ("bad posts") suggest that you did the right thing deleting. As for bad audits complaints, forget this nonsense and delete as you see fit - use the power and trust given to you by community. Posts deleted by moderators can't be bad audits [as explained here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318082/839601): _"audits based on flags handled by moderator are already as good as it gets - because these have passed human verification by a trusted reviewer..."_

Comment: _"...If reviewer clicks "good" on an answer that was considered bad by a moderator, chances are pretty damn high that reviewer was wrong."_

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm totally baffled that you interpret those post as meta disagreement of the actions, the first one the community disagreed with OP assertion that the answer shouldn't be deleted, and the other can be read as a general complain about the selection criteria of audits, not about your decision (remember, there has been other complains about using plagiarized and sketchy spam, too). The general sentiment here is, and what Cody is getting at: moderators, watch crap getting flagged, just take it out.

Comment: Thank you all for this details and information. specially "deceze", "Cody Gray" and "gnat". I've learnt a lot from it. Also @deceze I've read in your comment that maybe the _team_ is  _discussing that some flags should probably be consolidated/removed/changed_. So I wanted to know how can we suggest a new flag to them? The flag I have in mind is **Technically wrong answer**.

Comment: This is the flag that if had been there, if not all, but most of my declined flags would not be declined. And I really think we need it in order to help clear most of the garbage answers since may of them do not receive enough down-vote to get the moderators attention to be deleted

Comment: "Technically wrong answer" is one flag reason that will *never* get added, @ehs. Moderators aren't going to be able to determine the technical accuracy of every answer. They cannot be experts in every technology, and it's not even feasible to have a moderator-expert for each technology—there are just too many technologies and too many differences of opinion. For technical problems, you have two options: downvote and/or edit. Although I disagree with the way some of these flags were handled, please don't misinterpret any of my comments as suggesting flagging for technical inaccuracies.

Comment: @EhsanT Content does not need to be *deleted* because of inaccuracies. It merely has to be downvoted as a signpost that it is inaccurate. As Cody rightly explained, it's impractical for moderators to judge content. SO is a *peer reviewed* system. *You* are the peer. Moderators are meta users that can act outside the usual rules to handle exceptional cases, the same way that you can step outside to meta.SO to talk *about* SO. Moderators are not magazine editors which have to ensure that all printed content is accurate.

Comment: @deceze. Fair enough. I will use down-vote from now on, on answer that I think are wrong. But I was not talking about inaccuracy. I was talking about providing wrong information to the OP and future visitors that may search and reach to this question and answer. I think those contents should be deleted. anyway thanks again for the clarification...

Comment: I also have read a lot about deleted comments and how comments are _not meant to be of any lasting value_ or _second-class citizens_, But the [first answer in my list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41559330/1908331) I have down-voted it and also wrote a comment for the author about that his answer is wrong and why. But my flag was declined(now I know why and accept it), and also my comment was deleted. I just want to say I did what I thought is correct, But it seems that the moderator didn't like it...

Comment: @deceze, I'm so sorry to bother you here, but again I've flaged [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41656279/1908331) and again it got declined. Can you please please explain to me why and how on earth this flag has been declined?!? are these moderators really doing their job?! Do they even look at the answers before declining the flags?!?

Comment: @EhsanT Mostly likely the mod didn't look at *the question*. In the default mod UI, we see flagged answers devoid of context. And without context that answer looks like *an answer*, even if a terribly poor one. Digging deeper to discover the context takes time, which sometimes we don't have. In this case a custom flag explaining why this answer wasn't one would have been less ambiguous.

Comment: @deceze Thanks. I posted another question and explained the new situation and within a minute the answer got deleted but my declined flag still exists. And believe me, any any sane  person would find _that answer_ as a garbage post not a valid answer. But thank you for your valuable help :)