# Again a "not an answer" flag has been declined when the answer uses a completely unrelated language

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, moderation

Two days ago, I posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341378/why-were-my-flags-declined) about why some of my "not an answer" flags have been declined. I read all the comments and understood the reasons and tried to change my method for flagging.

Just a few minutes earlier, I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656279/1908331). The question is using the **C++** programming language. The answer has nothing to do with C++; actually it has nothing to do with programming or answering the question at all. As it seems to me, the author has just copied some part of an HTML page (an incomplete part, even) and just pasted that as an answer. It should be so obvious to anybody that this is not an answer.

But surprisingly the moderator who reviewed my flag thought differently...

My question is, why and how on earth could a moderator consider this as an answer? Or even an attempt to answer?

The reason for declining my flag is:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Really? No evidence? Does he need any more evidence than the answer itself?

Comment: That answer shouldn't be deleted; it should be vaporized.

Comment: Moderators do not always look at the question, but just the title of the question. You should not use generic flags for something like this, but instead use a custom flag so you can provide a better description. At a glance, this answer *would* appear to answer some sort of question, albeit with horrible formatting. Pointing out that it has blatantly nothing to do with the question completely changes what they're looking for. Your comment you left there would've been a much more helpful flag.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I know and if I had the power, I would do it immediately. Unfortunately the moderator declined my flag though something else.

Comment: @animuson, Thanks for your comment, will do it from now on, unfortunately I didn't think that some moderator would really consider this answer valuable enough to keep it on SO. when I saw my flag was declined, then I put the comment :) but thank you

Comment: @animuson Your comment seems to imply that none of the generic flags should ever be used as we can't rely on the people reviewing those flags to actually read the questions. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Blackwood Not at all. The generic NAA flags are meant for blatantly obvious situations, where users have asked followup questions, just posted a thank you, or otherwise. Stuff that a reasonable person could just *look* at with no other context and immediately hit the delete button. If the moderator needs to look further into the flag than that, you probably need to use a custom flag and explain in detail why, because chances are it's not immediately obvious.

Comment: @Blackwood, There are many many answers that are obvious stuff. (Take a peek into the first few answers [here](http://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=nato_score+desc&commit=Go)). We can tell that those are NAAs even without looking at the title of the question.

Comment: Boy oh boy, whoever declined that wasn't even paying attention. That answer needed to be deleted, even if it *was* posted to an HTML question. Everyone keeps telling you that NAA flags are meant for "blatantly obvious situations" as if this wasn't a blatantly obvious situation. This *is* something that "a reasonable person could just look at with no other context and immediately hit the delete button". It is the very definition of such a thing. It is very tiring and concerning to continually see Meta posts where people have flagged obvious garbage, and moderators are unwilling to do their job.

Comment: @bhargav Are you actually telling me that you needed the title of the question to see that the flagged answer was garbage in need of deletion? Even putting aside topicality, this is unintelligible gibberish, doesn't contain the answer to any question whatsoever, and was clearly copy-pasted from somewhere where it was copyrighted by x_kittykitty_x (which makes it plagiarism, since there's no link to x_kittykitty_x's original content). Sure, the question title would have made it even more obvious, but jeez, if we can only get "I have the same problem" deleted, you all can be replaced by a regex.

Comment: Strangely enough there also was a *No action needed* review in the Late Answers queue. ...

Comment: Not at all @Cody, I've never seen the title of any post out of the 8.5k posts that I've deleted in the past 54 days. The comment was meant as a reply to Blackwood's statement that none of the bad answers can be flagged as NAA. The title was with reference to animuson's previous comment. (There certainly was a context to my comment). As far as "jeez" and the other statement, I'm not sure if a regex could replace a human moderator. I don't think that the regex would classify [this](//stackoverflow.com/a/41052316) as an answer. However if you still feel that a regex is better, Please ask a FR.

Comment: Googling `x_kittykitty_x` brings up various results of an adult nature. Maybe it was an attempt to see if SO would accept HTML for spam purposes.

Comment: Exceptional situations tend to be non-obvious, so exception handlers should only step in into non-obvious situations. I'm sure the LQRQ would have got this case right, since they are shown context _by default_. Situations where stuff is obvious should be left to the queue, and moderators dedicate time to non-obvious situations.

Comment: @CodyGray Please settle down. You can pretend it's blatantly obvious as much as you want, but it really isn't. The last sentence of that looks like a legitimate explanation/answer to a piece of code that a new user wasn't able to figure out how to format properly. Stuff like that gets flagged as VLQ and NAA all the time, so moderators are used to seeing invalid flags like that. Without knowing that it had nothing to do with the question at hand (which is C++), I probably would have declined it too.

Comment: "Settle down"? I don't know what that is supposed to mean, @animuson. Don't patronize me, I'm not a child. I'm not pretending anything. I'm looking at it out of context and trying to evaluate it as I would if it were flagged. I can't find any redeeming value in that answer whatsoever, and the defense that has been offered strikes me as utterly ludicrous. The last sentence doesn't look like *anything* legitimate to me. If stuff like this gets flagged as VLQ/NAA "all the time", and moderators aren't deleting it, then that is a serious problem. You also ignored the plagiarism problem.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, you're one in a few there. Problem is, there are plenty of users here who *don't* think it is that straight-forward and freaking out because someone didn't see what you see is quite unwarranted. It's no one's job to sit around diving into every flag - it's the *flagger's* job to accurately describe the situation, and a generic NAA flag just doesn't accurately describe this particular situation. And yes, users flag crappy answers that are still answers all the time. Poor formatting is not a good reason to flat-out delete something.

Comment: I recognize, of course, that one cannot please everyone. My hope is that the number of people who freak out about very low-quality posts remaining on the site will outnumber the people who freak about these posts getting deleted, and then we can start making some actual headway. I do agree, though, that more descriptive flags are a good solution, and I tend to use them when I flag something. What makes that confusing advice is there have been moderators recently (in Meta comments, don't have a link at the moment) asking for custom flags *not* to be used because they're much harder to process.

Comment: @CodyGray It's blatantly obvious that it's a low quality post, but without the context of the question, it's less obvious that it wouldn't have been salvageable through editing. As for plagiarism, sorry, that's just nonsense. It may or may not be a violation of copyright, but firstly that's different from plagiarism, and secondly, unlike plagiarism, that generally requires the copyright holder to take action.

Comment: Bah. The NAA flag description states that it is for a post that does not attempt to answer ***the*** question - that's an inherently context-dependent definition. While I have to concede that @CodyGray is *technically* wrong to assert that this can be seen to be a non-answer without context (without context, maybe the original question was x_kittykitty_x asking how to fix their HTML code), the real problem here is that giving users an inherently context-dependent flag and then having mods review it without context (*even when the post obviously sucks*) is an awful process in the first place.

Comment: Also, once again, this is a problem that could've been avoided if we just [stopped passing VLQ and NAA flags on to the diamond mods](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314734/1709587). That process seems to do nothing but harm.

Comment: @MarkAmery We are working towards that. Currently, moderators only see NAA flags after they've been sitting around unhandled by reviewers for 15 or 30 minutes (I forget which one). But as another comment above points out, this did get into review where it had context, and some user even clicked the No Action Needed button (clearly wrong, I would've expected a reviewer to at least attempt to edit it if they didn't figure out it was nonsense).

Comment: @animuson According to [Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658) it's one hour delay on SO, unless that was changed.

Comment: @animuson Moderators don't see NAA flags newer than an hour... *unless* we filter for them (/admin/dashboard?flagtype=answernotananswer). Usually it isn't a factor, but when the queue is one/two digits, it's easy to clear out all the NAA flags by 'accident'. Once you're in the flow, you tend to just keep going.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I posted [a feature request to change the "the" into "any"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag) two years ago. No change so far.

Comment: Look at that airplane design, haha, it won't ever fly! - Why?!? Well, for one, it lacks wings, and secondly, no engines. - You could have EXPLAINED that.

Comment: @animuson, I've been reading all the comments, But your last comment surprised me. The flag was "Not an answer" and I think any sane person would find that answer a garbage post and know what is actually wrong with that post, because it was not an answer what so ever. And I can not accept it that a responsible moderator would find it otherwise. In my opinion only a lazy moderator who just wanted to get rid of flags would randomly click on accept or decline for any flag would do that!

Comment: The comments here have demonstrated that there is a difference of opinion between users on whether this answer *looked* like an answer. Users trying to pin it on poor moderation are just playing the blame game. "Omg something I completely disagree with, moderators are getting so lazy!" A moderator didn't catch on to the flag, didn't see the answer in the same light - the user brought more detail to the situation, and the problem got resolved. Moderators are by no means perfect, and I'm sure all the users complaining would make their fair share of mistakes if they were moderating as well.

Comment: @animuson: Regarding your claim "demonstrated that there is a difference of opinion between users", can you back that up by mentioning the nick of one user who has sided with the moderator about this case?

Comment: I am not blaming _moderators_ in any way. I do not know how hard they are working to keep clean and high quality content in SO and remove the garbage. But I'm sure the amount of daily garbage removal is very high. But I'm just saying _the_ moderator who has declined _the_ certain answer, had not payed enough attention and I'm sure if he had done it, he would certainly accepted the flag. That's all.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Me, for one, and the fact that quite a few people upvoted the comment. Comments saying it is obvious may have more votes, but I also don't expect people to be posting useless "I agree it's not obvious" comments here because that doesn't contribute to the conversation whatsoever. If all you're going to do here is nitpick, then I'm really not interested in conversing with you.

Comment: @animuson, so lack of comment upvotes implies that people do not agree with it? That is silly. For starters, because the answer was deleted and thus most people cannot check anymore. Secondly, because there is no null model for what an amount would be enough to prove that people agree with it. Your behavior in this discussion is unwelcome.

Comment: The answer was pure garbage and it was obvious. Errors happen to everyone, even mods, it would have been easier for everyone to admit it in the first place.

Comment: If this ultimately comes down to moderators making wrong decisions because they are missing the context of the answer, then maybe the interface should be changed for them to actually give them some context? Show the tags of the question, show the account age of the post’s author, and other information to *give them context* (that was that user’s first post and the user has no reputation, so maybe we should consider that the flag might actually be correct and check it with more detail?).

Comment: @MarkAmery: yet we process NAA flags 50/50 with the community, at what I wager is a *pretty damn low error rate*. Is the community ready to double their flag handling capacity?

Comment: I agree that it'd be nice if it were easier for mods to see more context. OTOH, that'd still slow them down. IMHO, the onus is on the flagger to make the decision about providing enough context to evaluate their flag. However, many flaggers aren't aware of this problem, so it should be made explicit on the [flag-posts help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), with a reminder on the flag popup to 'Use the "in need of moderator intervention" flag and give a comment to direct the mod to the required context' if a flagged post needs context not visible in the post itself.

Comment: @poke: note that the answer doesn't fit the normal NAA flag reasons. Yes, it is a piece of garbage littering the page, but it basically is a *very, very wrong answer*, as it was answering a completely different question. Adding more context to a list of 50 flags is not going to make the job any easier.

Comment: @MartijnPieters *Is the community ready to double their flag handling capacity?* - unsure, but considering that I frequently don't have the ability to review LQP because the queue is empty (at least with my filters), I'd say that we certainly are ready to step up our review rate considerably.

Comment: My neighbor called and said that my border collie had knocked over his trash cans again and scattered food scraps all over the driveway, and would I please come clean it up. I went over and clearly saw the muddy footprints of my terrier and a bunch of paper spilling out of the knocked-over can, so I left the mess the way it was and called my neighbor back to tell him that he was mistaken.

Comment: @poke *"“We cannot judge an answer that is flagged as "not an answer" when the only information that we see, that is, the answer alone as well as the question title” I don't get this. In the flag dashboard, all it takes is one click to show the question body, and I routinely do this when a NAA flag isn't immediately obvious. Or do you SO guys get a different interface from the rest of the network?"* – [Gilles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag-the-question-%e2%86%92/286270#comment156539_286270)

Comment: @animuson, “instead use a custom flag” doesn't work because when someone posts a bunch of links that look like they might answer the question but actually don't and I use a custom flag to explain that, it gets rejected with “[Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/22437)”.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I declined the flag, because I saw the post *in isolation* in the flag handling queue. Without context, it looked like any other *new user doesn't know how to format so HTML looks messed up* answer, but otherwise looked like an attempt to answer, specifically because of the sentence at the end:

[image: deleted answer in question]

It didn't look like any of the [normal NAA flag reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553). It wasn't asking for clarification, it wasn't thanking anyone, it wasn't a me-too answer, it wasn't asking a new question, etc.

But yes, if I had opened the question, it would have been obvious this was just a piece of garbage littering the page. It *is* an attempt at answering, albeit the wrong question (what, we'll never know).  My apologies.

What happened is that when processing yet another few-100 NAA flags, it isn't always an efficient use of moderator time to open each question page. You can help us be more efficient by flagging garbage like that with a custom flag or leaving a comment underneath the answer (we can expand answer posts to see the comments too).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Actually I wrote a comment, but it was too late and the flag was declined.

Comment: @EhsanT: I saw; it was posted 15 minutes after I reviewed the post, unfortunately.

Comment: it's amazing to me how you guys can remember every flag you handle after hundreds of generic ones

Comment: So, why are these posts presented to you _in isolation_? That seems strange...

Comment: @canon: all flags are presented in batches of 50. There's a lot of information in the moderator flag queue, and we can click through or load just the post in full (with comments) in the queue page, as well as see more of the question the answer was posted to. The other answers and the full text of the question are not there however. This does make handling a large number of flags efficient.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would it be an acceptable compromise to show just the title of the question, as opposed to either the whole thing or nothing at all?

Comment: @duplode: just the title of the question is what we start with. You can reveal the body of the question as needed.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for clarifying it -- I missed that detail amidst the tangle of comments to the question above.

Comment: Seems to me that if a custom flag is the only way to get a post actually looked at properly, all the other flag options should be removed

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sure, very helpful. Because that option only can be handled by volunteer elected moderators, of which we have an endless supply, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Does dripping sarcasm fit the new code of conduct? ;)