# What's meaning of the diamond after the name or website?

Tags: support

There is a diamond after the website name:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

There is a diamond after the username:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

What's the meaning of that?

Comment: Strangely enough, this isn't actually a dupe. But given the tooltip says "moderator" when you hover over the diamond, maybe that's why.

Comment: It's a warning of lethal danger within, kinda like the 'DANGER of DEATH' signs on electricity substation enclosures :)

Comment: Great job blurring Adam's name there. We totally don't know who that is!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for the diamond after a username is to state that this user is a moderator. Also, a moderator on other sites. Also, the user could possibly be an employee as well.

Comment: how to become a moderator?

Comment: Well depends on which site you go on often. Let's use SO for example. Here is a [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141099/eligibility-requirements-for-stack-overflow-moderator-elections) to the requirement to be a mod. @aircraft

Comment: alternatively you could be hired as an employee, some employees (though not all) have moderator privileges.

Comment: That is also true. If you look at the user, Adam Lear, he works at SO.

Comment: This is actually an employee.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I really don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @narusin: Adam Lear is an employee, not a moderator. Employees can be given moderator privileges when that's a requirement for their work. Adam is a Community Manager so is a moderator on all sites in the network.

Comment: (Very minor note: Adam is currently a dev, not a CM, according to his profile.)

Answer (score 8):

Users with diamonds after their names are either moderators (volunteers selected or elected from the user base) or employees (usually Community Managers or developers). This indicates that they can act unilaterally to close questions or delete posts. They can also suspend or delete users should the need arise.

There are a few users who are moderators on multiple sites (myself included) but if a user has diamonds on lots of sites then that indicates that they'll be an employee rather than a moderator.

Comment: Your Second paragraph helps a lot

Comment: Does moderators get paid for doing there job?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil we're volunteers, so no we don't get paid.