# Does Android really sponsor [listview]?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonym-process, sponsored-tags

The [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview) tag seems to have an android logo on it:

> [image]

That seems like a bug, as it shouldn't be possible for a company to sponsor  a generic tag like this:

> ***"Generic tag names that do not associate with any particular brand, company or entity, have no sponsorship icons."*** ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104757/203057))

Turns out a recently applied synonym is the culprit. This synonym is incorrect and should be removed.

Comment: Also [android-editText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-edittext) have an android logo on it and also icon changed of [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio)

Comment: @NileshRathod: That's Android-specific. I don't see a problem there.

Comment: previously that  tag `[android-edittext]` has no icon that's the reason @Cerbrus

Comment: Maybe android bought some extra tag sponsorships.

Comment: And also `[listview]` has [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/listview/synonyms) `[android-listview]` that's the reason it displaying the icon of android in tag

Comment: Ugh, why the heck 4 users approved that synonym?! https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: I can't wait for Android to sponsor [tag:ios] for the lol.

Comment: **Note** some tag are without android icon like [android-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-dialog/info), [android-constraintlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-constraintlayout/info), [android-imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-imageview/info), [android-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-recyclerview/info), [android-gridlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-gridlayout/info),  [android-camera](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-camera/info), [android-viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-viewpager/info)

Comment: Yet another example of the broken synonym system: synonym was suggested back in '15 but somehow just got approved 6 hours ago...

Comment: The synonym is now removed... might take a little bit to show properly caching and all that...

Comment: @JonClements: fixed. Can this be [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention! [listview] having the android icon is indeed a bug; it has been fixed now and we apologize for the confusion.

Some other android-related tags (like [android-studio]) are part of a new sponsorship package we just started running, while some other android tags (like [android-dialog]) did not make it into this package at this time :)

Let us know if this helps clarify things!

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Although this is not the first time this has gone wrong.

Comment: Are you an Android rep or a StackExchange employee?

Comment: @cat: He is from the ad ops team at Stack Overflow (source [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373240/sponsored-tag-bug-again/373297#comment625454_373297))

Comment: Should have a ♦ if he's an employee.

Comment: @jhpratt Nope, employees can choose to not have the ♦

Comment: @DavidG I'm aware. My point is that if he's going to be posting things officially, he should enable it.

Comment: @jhpratt But they may not perform any moderator activities. There's an argument to have an "employee" indicator, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: @jhpratt See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341671/1663001) for more discussion.