# Wrong synonyms for list-view tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

listview tag is synonym with android-listview and that causes to show the android icon beside the tag `listview`, while it is a general tag, a name of a general control that exists in almost all programming languages.

This question for instance: [How can I pass the data from one listview into another listview located in a different form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115047/how-can-i-pass-the-data-from-one-listview-into-another-listview-located-in-a-dif)

It in above question has nothing to do with android, because listview also exists in C#.

General names, like TextBox, Label, ... must not be synonym with product specific tags.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376143/does-android-really-sponsor-listview

Comment: *It in above question has nothing to do with android* [**`listview`** also exists in android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview)

Comment: @NileshRathod if the question already exists, then in the other question why did you suggest to add it? ;))

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani i'm just telling your that `listview` also exist in android also you are right in your comment that `listview` in C# displaying android icon

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani `if the question already exists` which question

Comment: oh you are right, i got it wrong ;) sorry.