# Who is the sponsor of the Generics tag?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, tags, sponsored-tags

There are some of the tags with an icon and as stated in the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251364/3764965) of the question [How can I set an icon on a tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251363/3764965):

> The icons are sponsorships; you need to contact the Stack Exchange sales team to sponsor a tag; it is one of the ways Stack Exchange makes money from the site. The icon is provided by the sponsor of the tag.

I noticed that the [`generics`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/generics/info) tag has now an icon and I wonder since the tag is not relevant to the only language nor a single provider (such as Azure or Google...).

[image: Icon]

- [Screenshot Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3CVC.jpg)
- [ScreenShot Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUSBp.png)

  Who is the **sponsor** of the [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) tag and what is the icon meaning? Can one somehow help to set an icon for example [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array)?

---

**Observations:**

<sub>(please, help me to keep this up)</sub>

1. The icon looks somehow like an Android robot waving with a hand and wearing a red cape.

   - My thought has been confirmed with the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ7Kt.png) (thanks to [Erik von Asmuth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth)).
2. The issue seems not the time-zone related neither the country related. One user in the United Kingdom can see it while another one cannot. Also, the catching issues might produce the inconsistent results.
3. The icon aside of [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) affects all <strike>most</strike> of the Kotlin related tags, such as [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin), [kotlin-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-extension), [kotlin-android-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-android-extensions), etc...

Comment: I don't see a sponsor icon on that tag.

Comment: Probably some [generic toothpaste.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_brand)

Comment: That blurry logo [doesn't show in the desktop view](https://imgur.com/a/e5cJgWM). At least for me.

Comment: No repro,  not matters the browser. Even on Android apps on different version no Issue.

Comment: @yivi: Strange. It's there for me on desktop in Chrome and Edge

Comment: I wonder if geo-targeting is possible for tag sponsorships?

Comment: Some A/B testing going on there?

Comment: @Stijn: Maybe. But would be a strange targeting that hits Austria and misses Spain and Belgium.

Comment: Can't reproduce in the UK. No icon for me here.

Comment: Further digging: Kotlin has an identical image for me, it no longer has the Kotlin logo. Many Kotlin-related subjects have this image too.  I think something's going wrong with the tag sponsorships again, it certainly wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Oh, apparently the large version of the image is [this one](https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgKDbnsWyFhABGAEyCGnPt2JivLfK), it's an Android robot with cape and Kotlin logo.

Comment: It's Kotlin-Man just before he takes off to the android universe

Comment: Can reproduce in Hungary.

Comment: The icon is named ["DryOs"](//i.stack.imgur.com/DryOs.png). Not sure if it is significant, but it could be the name of something.

Comment: I'm in the UK and I **can** see the icon so this really does seem to be random.

Comment: @Turnip: Thanks for the insight. Now we see it's not the country related.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think that is just a random name given to the file. For example, the android icon is named `bk9VA.png` - https//i.stack.imgur.com/bk9VA.png

Comment: @gparyani oddly enough, I can reproduce this in Chrome (70.0.3538.102) in the US

Comment: Can reproduce in Brazil (all desktop browsers).

Comment: @jrh I can reproduce it now too. It was probably just CDN caching that caused it to not show up initially in certain localities.

Comment: The inconsistency looks more and more like [the usual](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). I can now I can see the logo from Madrid, Spain as well. Any reason not to believe that Google is behind the sponsorship, as usual?

Comment: Looks like a reincarnation of [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376143/4751173).

Comment: @Glorfindel: Thanks. I have tagged the [meta-tag:bug] as well.

Comment: The same icon is shown for kotlin, which is not a generic tag and not owned by google nor exclusively associated with the android platform

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The icon showing is relating to a sponsorship by Kotlin. We're investigating whether this is intentional - our current hypothesis is that this is an accidental side-effect of there being a redirect from "kotlin-generics" to "generics", and the sponsorship trying to target everything "kotlin-*".

update: testing in our QA environment suggests this is indeed likely the explanation; I'm trying to check with the person who created the entry.

update update: we've confirmed that this was the kotlin-generics redirect, and this has now been removed from the list; just waiting on cache to invalidate now...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with sponsorships.. are you saying kotlin chose this to be their new tag icon?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I can't answer that; all I can say (until I track down the right folks) is that there *is* a tag-sponsorship record that links "generics" to that icon, as part of a sponsorship by Kotlin

Comment: Stack Overflow has a QA environment? 

Comment: @Turnip we have one *in addition* to meta (which we unashamedly use as a smoke test), yes

Comment: @Turnip I wish we could use emoji's to react on comments... 

Comment: The test environment only consists of "did the change break meta?"  If meta is ok, that means it is ok to push the build to production because the meta users will test the rest

Comment: @psubsee2003 also, we don't need monitoring tools - twitter will tell us if there's a problem :) (these are jokes; we do actually take stability seriously, just to be clear)