# Aspose ad breaks responsive design

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sponsored-tags, design

[image]

Using custom views, I made a view combining Excel and VBA. As it contains Excel there is this sponsorship of Aspose. (Is it even something usefull?). However on mobile this ad isn't responsive as per screenshot. On the left you can see the last bit of the question, while on the right there is a start of the logo of Aspose.

Comment: This bug is independent of custom views, also occurs when only viewing [tag:excel]. It doesn't occur on the mobile version of the website, though, only when using responsive design. On the mobile version the sponsorship is not visible.

Comment: @ErikA The custom question list isn't available on mobile either ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention! We have raised this issue to our engineering team, who is responsible for Stack Overflow's responsive design. They should be taking a look shortly. This is a great catch and thanks again!

Comment: If you are an employee then it might be a good idea to complete your profile.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not even sure if saying they're an employee of the company in question or of SO. I guess the former? SO would probably require them to fill out the profile as an employee.

Comment: Employee of SO: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/8564218?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!-.x35QtPDaMa ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373297/4616087), [related discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341657/split-visualization-of-employee-and-moderator/341671#341671))

Comment: Why is this sponsor sponsoring a generic tag like [tag:file]?