# How can a low-rep user review a declined flag once the answer has been deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I recently got a declined "very low quality" flag, and Stack Overflow would like me to look at it before flagging other questions.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316064/gyp-err-build-error-stack-error-make-failed-with-exit-code-2/45817020#45817020) is shaded in red.

I assume that the answer I flagged has since been deleted (presumbably because it was indeed very low quality) because I don't see it on the question anymore.

IIRC it was in the late answers queue and seemed to have nothing to do with the question, just some random cut and paste text.  If so, it would be related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341596/again-a-not-an-answer-flag-has-been-declined-when-the-answer-uses-a-completely).  But I could have made a mistake.

I understand that 10K+ rep users can view deleted posts.  Is there any way for me to look at the post I flagged?

Comment: Although you can't see deleted answers *in situ*, you should still be able to see the review page for any reviews that you completed, regardless of your reputation. In this case, that would be [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17108495).

Comment: @Cody thanks, and please bear with me, but how did you find that page?  I look in my [review history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573061/c8h10n4o2?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=1)  and don't see my review there.

Comment: Ah…you're right. That's the part you can't do, because you can't see deleted posts in your review history. Normally, when a flag is declined, the post is *not* deleted, so this isn't a problem. The only time you'd need to review a review action on a deleted post is if you made the *wrong* choice, in which case your review ban would come with a link to the incorrectly reviewed post(s). But in this case…yeah, you can't find it. I only found it because I'm a moderator. This needs to be fixed. It's probably been raised before, but I'm not sure if it was here or MSE.

Comment: @Cody thanks.  FWIW I didn't get a ban, only a warning, but I feel that my actions were entirely appropriate.  The question was a javascript question, and the answer was how to install the C compiler.  I commented "how does this have anything to do with the question?" and flagged as VLQ.  Was that the wrong choice?

Comment: Hehe, well, in [that question you linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341596/again-a-not-an-answer-flag-has-been-declined-when-the-answer-uses-a-completely), I am on record disagreeing with Martijn about precisely this issue, so I might not be a good one to ask. :-) I would have flagged it as "not an answer", and I would have validated either a NAA or VLQ flag on it (they're the same to me) if I were the moderator who processed that flag. I *do* evaluate answers in the context of the question they're posted to. If they're *blatantly* unrelated, I delete. Opinions vary, though.

Comment: @CodyGray - [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed) is a related feature request on Meta.SE for exposing deleted content to reviewers, but I don't think a similar request has been made for flags. I could see adding that as new feature request or an extension of the one I linked.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Normally you can find all reviews you've done in the [review history for the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history), even if the post is deleted.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 The question's title that will take you to the post itself isn't clickable, but where it said how you reviewed it is and will take you to the review page. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/x93nV.png

Comment: @DonaldDuck Got it, thanks!