# Why are answers for completely unrelated languages attempts to answer the question?

Tags: discussion

On the recent question [Can (a ==1 && a== 2 && a==3) ever evaluate to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/369450), a diamond moderator posted this comment:

> Moderator note: Stack Overflow has had a history of people chiming in with answers in different languages to the one in question. These are attempts to answer the question because they are solutions to the general problem, albeit in a different language. Please refrain from flagging them as "not an answer". Having said that, please also refrain from posting more answers in different languages - there is a reason this question is specific to JavaScript, as pointed out by comments under some of these other answers, and there is a reason we like our language-specific questions to remain so.

Now, *the question* is about a unique quirk in JavaScript, and appropriate answers *should* answer how it is or is not possible in JavaScript. This is not an algorithm or pattern question in which an example from another language could be applicable (e.g., bubble sort or MVC). Nor is *the question* about a shared API used by multiple languages (e.g., Cocoa from Objective-C or Swift). Other languages may have somewhat related quirks because a similar operator is involved, but the solutions and reasons would be specific to each language (e.g., JavaScript does not support operator overloading while many other languages do).

The question [A minor change to the description of the “not an answer” flag: “the question” → “a question”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229/369450) is related, but that is a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) asking for a wording change to the "not an answer" flag. The result of that was either inconclusive, or no action was taken from what I can tell.

The question [Again a “not an answer” flag has been declined when the answer uses a completely unrelated language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341596/369450) is related, and a diamond moderator responded explaining why the flag was declined (the tools are less than ideal).

The current message for the "not an answer" flag is:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Martijn Pieters's answer to ["When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/369450) lists several scenarios for when to flag answers as "not an answer". However, I don't think this specific scenario is addressed (I know it's hotly contested). The other answers do not attempt to answer *the question*. These other answers aren't wrong or misunderstanding *the question*. They answer different questions to different answers not posed by *the question*. They also don't answer the underlying cause of *the question* (e.g., an X-Y problem).

So to reference the apples and oranges image, *the question* is an apple, and these other answers should be considered oranges. Can an orange really answer an apple? I like oranges as much as the next guy, but I don't think they belong in a bushel of apples.

With that all in mind, why should posted answers about completely unrelated languages be considered attempts to answering *the question* (i.e., not "not an answer") when they do not answer, aid, or provide a solution to *the question* itself or its underlying cause?

Comment: I think this has already been made pretty clear: ["*Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer! Do not use the "not an answer" flag for wrong answers. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/369450)

Comment: Do not use NAA for posts that you think *fail* to answer the question.  Even if you think a post doesn't *succeed* in answering the question, that doesn't make it NAA.  If you think a post *fails* to answer the question, downvote it.

Comment: @JDB My problem is they "do not attempt to answer the question", and I specifically reference '"When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?"'

Comment: To put a finer point on Servy's remark:  don't rely on moderators to judge the correctness of any given answer.  If the answer is wrong, we as the community have the power to show that.

Comment: I know that you reference it, but you don't seem to have understood it. NAA is for "Yeah! Me too!" or "I have a similar question". If the answer is attempting to answer the question, but is wrong (because they've misunderstood it, failed to read the tags, or are using the wrong technology) then that's a bad answer, but it's still an answer.

Comment: Or put another way... if the scenario you are encountering isn't listed in Martijn Pieters's answer, then you probably should not be using NAA.

Comment: @cpburnz The heuristic to know if a post is NAA is nice and simple.  Does the person that posted the answer think that they have posted an answer to the question?  If no, it's NAA.  If yes, it's not NAA.

Comment: Don't get tied up with "it's not an answer *to **this** question*", the emphasized portion of that statement isn't part of the criteria.

Comment: My comment was just a roundabout way of saying "I'm sorry for not anticipating that the question would blow up and people would start posting these answers, and now that things have turned out the way they have, I'd rather keep the answers because they offer additional insight into the general problem (and most of them acknowledge their nature anyway) than delete them just because a few users are raising a stink about how they don't exactly fit, because there's as yet no way to move them into their own questions without bothering a CM about it when they have more pressing issues to deal with."

Comment: In all seriousness: Sometimes things unfold in less than ideal ways, and do so *spectacularly*. Reversing this then entails undoing massive amounts of effort that has gone into making those things happen in the first place, some of it good, but misplaced. When our tools to resolve the situation are themselves less than ideal, you have to make compromises.

Comment: Yay for systems that serves the needs of humans instead of the other way around!

Comment: What happens if the post is an attempt to answer a *non-programming* question? Should those be handled differently than "wrong language" answers that arguably attempt to answer *a* programming question? For example, "Beryllium has four protons. See this essay on Moby Dick for more infomation." Is that NAA or just downvotable?