# Flag declined... but why exactly?

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

Today I came across an answer I did not understand. It seemed like an okayish answer, but it did not match the question at all.

It basically said "For the second part of your question, just replace this by that in your code". Except that there was no second part and the code that should be replaced did not exist in the question either. At first I checked if the question had been edited, but it had not been.

So I commented and asked whether this was maybe pasted into the wrong browser window. I also flagged it as NAA, because whatever it was meant to be, it was not an answer to that question. You did not need any specific programming knowledge to see that, it just did not add up.

So I was going to flag something else and a warning pops up, that my previous flag was declined.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27071399

> [image]

It seems two other reviewers agreed with me. One high-rep user did not, for reasons unknown.

Even the actual poster later came by and agreed that it had been posted in error and deleted it.

So what happened? What more does it need? I flagged it, the majority agreed, even the OP agreed, how much more can it be "Not an answer"?

To me as a user, this looks like a bug. *"a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"* is certainly not what happened, otherwise I would like the moderator to give me a hint.

Comment: Careful, meta-SO believes that even when the author knows that they posted the answer in the wrong question, it's still an answer and should not be flagged. Blame [this rant for that behavior](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer).

Comment: It's not "not an answer". It's a very bad answer. But it doesn't fit the very narrow definition of "not an answer". It's not about what "meta believes", it's about the definition of the flag. That other users on review agreed with you, or that the author eventually deleted the answer themselves, is irrelevant. And a moderator not agreeing with you is certainly not a "bug".

Comment: I absolutely agree with that meta post. A flag should not be used when I just think the answer is *wrong*. Voting will take care of that. The answer wasn't *wrong*, it was a **random piece of text that should have gone into a different browser window**. How is that still "an answer"? If that is an answer, what could possibly not be an answer?

Comment: Aren't reviewers at least required to read the comments on the post they review?

Comment: reviewers are not required to be experts in the posts that they review and comments on posts are not always accurate.

Comment: You mean moderators? They are not "required" to read anything in particular. If you are using NAA, reading the post itself should enough information. If more detail is needed, you need a tool that can communicate more detail. And even if they read the comments, they are in no way obliged to agree with the comments. That  was what happened here. If you do not want to use another tool (which is not guaranteed to work),  you can leave it in the community's hands. It worked this time! Yay!

Comment: @JoeW How much of an expert in anything do you need to be, to see that the Q and A are completely out of context, not even technically, but by plain English language? If the answer references two parts of the question and neither part is there, you don't even need to know how to program at all.

Comment: How hard is it to understand that the NAA flag isn't for judging the accuracy of an answer but if it is or isn't an attempt to answer it?

Comment: @yivi That is funny, because time and again (look at my post history on meta) I come here and complain about review audits that are not doable without going out of the review tool, and now you tell me that reviewers should not even read what is shown inside the review tool when they do their job... that is very conflicting information.

Comment: You keep saying "reviewers". Moderators are not "reviewers" in that sense. They are flag handlers. Those are different tasks with different expectations. Your flag was not declined by "reviewers", but by a moderator.

Comment: @JoeW How hard is it to understand that this is not about the accuracy? Did you read my post at all? The answer **was pasted into the wrong browser window**. It's not inaccurate, it was never meant to be an answer to that question **at all**. And it is visible to anyone reading both question and answer with basic English skills.

Comment: @JoeW If you think something I accidentally paste into the wrong browser window should count as an attempt to answer the question, then I really don't know what should not. How much more "not an answer" can something get from "oopsie, wrong window"?

Comment: You may want to read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer).

Comment: The English phrase "Not an Answer" applies equally to answers that *syntactically* aren't answers (eg. another question) & also to answers that are *categorically* of no merit (JS response to a Java question). The current state of flag moderation tools make enforcing the latter of that nigh-impossible however, & as a result, NAA flags *can't* enforce that, even though it continues to *sound* like they should. The fact that this continues to trip up almost everyone at some point seems to heavily imply some change needs to occur with the language, or even with the "Not an Answer" phrase itself.

Comment: There is a lingering question since NAA was neutered some years ago -- what *other* flag can we use to dispose of *syntactically valid* but otherwise nonsensical answers to questions? Leaving aside (for now) the initial goal to alleviate moderators from the burden of judging those questions without the technical background necessary to see them as what they are, truth is the answer has always been **none** so far. VLQ won't make it. RoA is inappropriate IMHO. It's only custom flags, or down / delete votes (which don't cut it either). A solution to this problem would be welcome.

Comment: I think they don't want people use the NAA flag for answers that are answering the wrong question because technically that reasoning applies to partial answers, answers where the user may have misunderstood the question, answers that are alternatives to what was asked, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's the party line, but my point was that we do not have equivalent alternatives (we used to, but no longer) and that has been becoming a problem for quite a while now.

Comment: See, this is why we need a solid [Off-Topic flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377551/7795130). People feel very strongly about "not an answer" only being applied to things that are strictly not answers since the moderators shouldn't be expected to know anything technical about the post they're evaluating, but some things are "answers" but completely unrelated to the question, such that anyone could make that judgement without technical expertise.

Comment: @zcoop98 [preach to the choir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229/792066)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Sorry, my comment was for nvoigt, not you. I wasn't arguing against their being an alternative for this situation; I think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

> I also flagged it as NAA, because whatever it was meant to be, it was not an answer to that question.

Right. But it is an answer to the on SO on-topic question *Why can't my FirebaseUser not log in* and therefore you can't use NAA flags to get rid of it.

Spend a downvote on it. And delete votes. NAA flags are the wrong tool here. Maybe, if you're really so disgruntled about the not immediate removal you could try a custom flag and explain why that answer is better deleted. Something like: *This new user posted by accident a valid answer to the wrong question, an honest mistake. Can you spare them the downvotes and maybe later quality ban issues by deleting the answer instead of waiting for 20K-ers to do the job*. Depending on the mod that might lead to success ... no guarantees.

Comment: I don't understand. Where did you get "Why can't my FirebaseUser not log in" from?

Comment: @nvoigt I have a spoiled brain, or a lively imagination. You pick.

Comment: But the NAA flag specifically says "Any post that attempts to answer **the question** [...] is still an answer!". Where does it say "it's Jeopardy, anything you can make up a question for is a valid answer". The answer should answer *that specific question*. Again, if it's wrong in my opinion, that's not for flagging, but if it's text pasted into the wrong browser window without any context to the question... it should not be flagged NAA, because grammatically you could make up a sentence structure that could theoretically serve as a question to that copy/paste error? That does't make sense.

Comment: What the flag text says is wrong and has been for 6 to 8 weeks. It should read *Any post that attempts to answer **a** question [...] is still an answer!*

Comment: So... "3 cucumbers, a camel and light sunlight, but only on Wednesdays after lunch." **is** a valid answer to the question "How do I display a bar chart in Visual Basic"? Because that's what you are saying... it's *an* answer... just not to that exact question, but hey, why be *that* nitpicky about it.

Comment: @nvoigt No. An Answer has to be at attempt at answering any **valid** Question on Stack Overflow. "3 cucumbers, a camel and light sunlight, but only on Wednesdays after lunch" cannot possibly be answering any valid programming Question :) Though most "Not an Answer" are "I'm having this issue too. Any updates?" or "Here is my code <code>. Please help me fix this too" or "Check this out: <link>"

Comment: So you think that "Since you said you use Cucumber, please add the line "doit=7;" to your cucumber.config" is a valid answer to "How do I display a bar chart in Visual Basic" that never said a word about Cucumber? Because it's still completely out of context. Not in the right/wrong realm, but in the "does not compute in that context" realm.

Comment: It's not a valid answer, of course not. But it's not a good target for a NAA flag.

Comment: @nvoigt Yes, that is correct. I didn't invent this, I'm just trying to make sense out of this madness for you.

Comment: Well, okay, thanks, I guess? Madness it is indeed.

Comment: @nvoigt One thing that it's easy to miss amongst all this, is that nobody is telling you they agree with the rules. We are just trying to help you in having a better time using the existing tools. To change the rules would require a different kind of post, different kind of analysis, and that would be a completely kind of conversation. While I can understand your frustration, I can see the reason for this madness to be this way. I don't like it, but I don't think changing it would be particularly easy to scale to SO size.

Comment: @nvoigt if my answer helped you please upvote and mark it as correct  ;)

Comment: Well... lets say of all answers it was the most comforting one m-) I still think it sucks, but that's not on you :)

Comment: Well, thinking about it, I have upvoted yours, but I don't want this marked as "solved", I still want that moderator tell me to my face that the official written guidelines are *wrong*, will not be updated on purpose and a copy/paste mistake **is** a valid answer. Let's see who sticks their head out to sell that with a straight face.

Comment: @nvoigt I'll ping Cody. His face is hidden by glasses but his answers are always to the point.

Comment: @nvoigt you've seem to have run into the absurdness of SO. [Half a decade after](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229/792066) we still have the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I would have probably done the same if I were you. The description for NAA literally states:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

That answer obviously did not fit that question: it was ***totally unrelated*** and thus **NEEDED TO BE DELETED** (as per the last part of the description pasted above). From the moderator's message, it's not clear why your flag was declined, but I agree with you and I think you were right to flag NAA.

Comment: Albeit, it's still an answer. A delete vote or a custom mod flag would have been a better option.

Comment: I think a good analogy is having a blue face-mask in a bag labelled "red face-masks". Granted, the blue face-mask is a face-mask just like everything else in the bag, but then, it still needs to be removed because it's not meant to be there.

Comment: While I agree that an NAA should have been the right option, currently it's not so. We can only wait until the NAA flags meaning changes. Meanwhile, a custom flag is what we need to use.