# Flag description for "not an answer" is unclear

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I flagged an answer as "not an answer" and it got declined. A quick google search yielded several meta posts that confirmed that it was probably correct to be declined.

The flag description for "not an answer" is:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. [...]

, which is precisely what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66198759/653473) is. The answer has no relevance to **the** question. It is answering a completely different, hypothetical question, which has not been asked, and, as such, *the post*, as it is, *does not attempt to answer **the** question*.

I'm hardly the first person confused by this, and I understand the purpose of "not an answer" *now* (after googling it), but the current description is misleading.

It should include a hint that the flag is to be used neither to assess technical correctness, **nor technical relevance**.

Comment: I think you're suppose to read it as "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer **a** question." (Implicitly: that can be asked on Stack Overflow) Please see [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) Any Answer that attempts to answer is not "Not an Answer", even if they do not answer the Question they are on, it's still an attempt. But I agree with you on the phrasing. I find Stack's lack of guidance of how to curate content disappointing.

Comment: Maybe. But as it stands, it says "the question". Not "a question" or "any question". And even if it did, it could be much clearer and less lawyer-y to avoid false flags.

Comment: A link to the meta post would probably be a good start. The first 50 flags could come with an extra bar on the top that links to relevant guidance for the particular flag picked (when the radio button is picked). Unfortunately, like most of us, you're learning it the hard way! :(

Comment: Your flag was never _declined_. It was automatically marked _disputed_ when the [review of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28322716) concluded it looks OK.

Comment: Related discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400870

Answer (score -1):

The NAA flag is difficult, because you have guess the first time, where the limit is,  to validate such an flag.

But in general:

**Everything** that is an answer, independent validity or correctness, is a valid answer and doesn't fall under the Category of a NAA flag, if you don't like it, simply downvote it.

What actually isn't an answer and doesn't fall under the other flags, will also not fall under the NAA flag.

Last I had a foreign language answer,  that I couldn't identify as such, and still got the NAA flag declined (and it was still deleted).

Comment: You had a NAA flag declined on a non-English answer? That sounds very much like a mistake. My guess is either the moderator who evaluated the flag mis-clicked, or you're misremembering the situation.

Comment: Indeed, the [FAQ for non-English content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content) explicitly says to flag such answers.