# Low quality flag declined

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, declined-flags

I recently flagged and VTC [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012582/looking-for-open-source-javascript-library-for-creating-erd-like-diagram-from-js) as it was asking for recommendation about a tool to create an ERD-like diagram from JSON.

Although this question got downvoted and put on-hold (A moderator choose to close it), my flag was still declined:

[image: Screenshot of declined flag]

The OP clearly wrote: **"Looking for open source javascript library"** and **"Any help or links to examples would be greatly appreciated"** in the question, so I don't understand why it was declined.

Was I wrong to flag this question? Would this might affect on my privileges to flag questions on SO?

Comment: If you voted to close it, why did you *also* flag it? What did you expect a moderator to do?

Comment: @CodyGray To make sure it's in the review queue of Close Votes questions

Comment: Okay, well that happens automatically when you cast a vote to close, so there's no reason to flag it twice. The "very low quality" flag goes into a different category, and there's no reason for a single question to be in both.

Comment: A VLQ flag was not suitable, there's a dedicated flag for questions looking for off-site resources such as libraries, which is the one you should've used.

Comment: @cybermonkey You're correct in the general sense, but this question is VLQ by SO standards since there is a specific rule against it and the question is all about asking for recommendations about libraries. It's like that a close vote counts - Even when it's for the wrong reason (And sometimes there are more than 1 reason to close a question). So I believe that declining it was maybe a bit too much. But I also know that this is not the end of the world. I ased this for the sake of the discussion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Was I wrong to flag this question?

No, but you picked the wrong reason.

This question should be closed as off-topic, because it is asking for library/tool/external resource recommendations. The correct way is to flag -> should be closed.

Or in your case, you have enough reputation to cast a close vote directly. No need to flag at all.

Closing means that the question gets put "on hold", where the OP gets a chance to edit it and bring it back to a format that is fine for SO, before it gets deleted. Similarly, other users than the OP could sometimes edit a closed question to turn it acceptable.

Very low quality however, is for posts that are beyond rescue. Some examples:

- Something completely random not related to programming
- A question posted as answer
- Some brief one-liner asking for clarification by the op, which should be a comment and not answer.
- Random chat comments like "I'm having this problem too", "Did you solve this?" or "Thanks!".
- Link-only answers that provide nothing but a link to an external site.

Such posts will not get closed, but deleted directly (after consensus of 5 reviews from user moderators), without any chance for the OP to fix the post.

> Would this might affect on my privileges to flag questions on SO?

Only if you repeatedly get a lot flags declined, or if your are somehow abusing the flagging system. A few flags declined here and there is nothing to worry about. Sometimes it is subjective if something should get closed/deleted, and then you may end up with declined flags even though you could be correct. Happens to everyone.

Comment: Aren't your middle three examples more suited for NAA flags than LQP?

Comment: VLQ doesn't put it up for deletion by reviewers, it just adds it to Triage where someone can flag it for closure, putting it in the close queue, where it would hopefully be flagged by 5 users for closure.  There is no deletion path for questions through review as a result of VLQ votes.  That said, it's better to just cast the close vote than force the question to go through so many extra steps before ending up where it needs to be (and risking bad reviewers reviewing it wrong).

Comment: @Vemonus It ends up in the same review. Either flag is fine, crap is crap.

Comment: @Servy Well... all those queues to the left and right only proves that moderation tools work very poorly on this site. Crap is crap, and should get deleted as soon as possibly, by involving as few user moderators as possible. All the "meta meta stack overflow" tasks introduced by those new review queues are just burdensome.

Comment: @Lundin Then don't suggest people use a VLQ flag, and instead tell them to use a closure flag, so that they aren't sending the post to a queue where it can get sent to the right queue.  Just have them send it to the right queue from the start.  Note how basically all of the "reasons to flag a post for VLQ" apply to answers.  Flagging *answers* for those reasons are fine, but as this is about a question, you should just be flagging for closure.

Comment: @Servy I did. "Or in your case, you have enough reputation to cast a close vote directly. No need to flag at all."  Although the reader of this answer this might not have enough rep to cast close votes. This answer is universal for answers too, and we can't close vote those.

Comment: @Lundin If they don't have the rep to cast a close vote then, the should be flagging for closure.  It's not "just as good", rather it's *much* better, and resolves that (rather likely) problem that the OP is pointing out.  The question is specifically asking about flagging questions, the issue mentioned wouldn't be an issue for answer, and would have a radically different answer.  You're not providing an answer that generalizes, instead you're simply *not answering the question asked*.  The question asked doesn't generalize to answers, and your attempt to discuss them makes your answer wrong.

Comment: @Servy What are you on about? "The correct way is to flag -> should be closed". Instead of making all these statements about what my answer says, you should try to actually read it. You could also post an answer of your own. I'm done talking with you now.

Comment: @Lundin And if that's all your answer said, then it would actually be correct.  Unfortunately you bury that one sentence in tons of information that's both wrong and inapplicable to the situation at hand.  That you said one correct thing doesn't change the fact that you've said lots and lots of incorrect things.  Perhaps you didn't notice that your answer, and your comments, actually contains other text than that one sentence.  You should try to actually read it.  That you don't care that you've saying a bunch of factually wrong things and also providing bad advice is rather sad.

Answer (score 2):

VLQ Flags are for those which warrant immediate deletion and aren't capable of putting on hold or closed.

Question asking for recommendations or technical problems can be put on hold or migrate to other SE sites if found fit.

VLQ Description:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question
>   is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be
>   removed.

From [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

> Very low quality (i.e. no amount of editing can salvage the post)
>   (only new posts scoring 0 or less)

Comment: Apart from this, Moderators have been giving [strict guidelines from community managers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288440/under-the-new-triage-system-when-and-how-should-moderators-act-on-very-low-qua/288450#288450) on how to handle these flags.

Comment: But don't you think that __Looking for open source javascript library__ is severe enough to flag? It don't must to be gibberish content - but a content that is clearly conflicting with the rule that __Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic__

Comment: @Alon, Nope, Use close votes for that. Usually the VLQ flag on questions is for troll posts (Aside: The decline reason should perhaps have been, "Use standard flags" instead of the "no evidence found", Not sure why the moderator who reviewed your post decided to go with that reason)

Comment: this strictness requirement is a [blatant nonsense](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318082/839601) and [you know that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341378/why-were-my-flags-declined?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment431483_341379) @BhargavRao - "delete as you see fit - use the power and trust given to you by community..."

Comment: @AlonEitan When there is a specific flag for recommendations question why shouldn't we use that first before directly qualify as very low quality otherwise every question which conflict with rule is considered as low quality.